# Max numeric valu of a varchar Column

Tags: mysql, sql, max, varchar

Below is my cloumn from mytable and it is VARCHAR. The values are coming in a txt file from a weather station. Using PHP all the values are imported into a Mysql DB. 
I need to select the max value from Outside which is (11,5) .
How can I do it?

```
Outside
-------
9,5
9,9
10,3
10,2
11,5
11,3
```

I tried

```
SELECT MAX( CONVERT( Outside, UNSIGNED ) )
```

This gives only 11

Comment: How do you define *Max*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `,` with `.` and use the auto convertion when multiplicating with a decimal number

```
SELECT max(replace(Outside, ',', '.') * 1.0)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18d1f/1)

Comment: Works fine thanks. How would you put this statement in php mysql_query?

Comment: Please, [don't use mysql_* functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). 
They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
Learn about **Prepared Statements** instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for a quick overview how to do it and why it is so important.